# Compiling ROS on RPI fails at opencv with undefined reference to 'header'

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ros

I'm trying to compile ROS (Robot Operating System) on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) following [these instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Debian) and got to the point to compile ROS, which fails at compiling opencv with `undefined reference to 'header'`:

```
[ 97%] Built target opencv_videostab
[ 98%] Built target opencv_haartraining_engine
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_createsamples
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.6: undefined reference to `header'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_createsamples] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'opencv2': 
  Command '/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j1 -l1' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I googled to try to figure out what header file might be missing, but unfortunately didn't get anywhere.

I hope somebody will have an idea about at least the directions to go from here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm going to answer my own question. I don't exactly know which dependency caused this particular error, but I had recompiled ffmpeg based on the instructions provided at http://ariandy1.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/raspberry-pi-rasbian-opencv/ and now I managed to get ROS to compile opencv.